# What does it mean a word "in" in a method's argument list in documentation?

Tags: javascript, mozilla, conventions

Sorry for possibly stupid question but I ask you to be lenient, cause I simply do not like to leave some gaps when I read docs.

Consider the following snippet from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent):

```
void initCustomEvent(
    in DOMString type,
    in boolean canBubble,
    in boolean cancelable,
    in any detail
);
```

As far ad I know, there is no such syntax in JavaScript like `void`. But this is simply a convention to tell, that the method does not return anything. (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

But what does it mean **in** ?

Comment: Interface Definition Language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language

Comment: @c.P.u1 you have the correct answer here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It mean the parameter is an *"in-parameter*", i.e. the value goes into the function, in contrast to *"out-parameters"* where the function adds data to that argument or that location in memory, which can then be used further by the calling code.

Here is an example from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProperties#get()) containing an "out-parameter":

```
void get(
  in string prop,
  in nsIIDRef iid,
  [iid_is(iid),retval] out nsQIResult result
);
```

And a JavaScript example:

```
function range(n, result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result.push(i);
    }
}

// to be called as
var foo = [];
range(10, foo);
console.log(foo); // shows [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

"out-parameters" are not popular in JavaScript, but seem to be more common in C or C++, which is the language Firefox is developed in.

[As hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175641/what-does-it-mean-a-word-in-in-a-methods-argument-list-in-documentation/17175706#comment24869477_17175641) by [c.P.u1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/858366/c-p-u1), this is not JavaScript syntax, this is simply a description of the interface. Mozilla developed and used [XPIDL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPIDL). From their documentation:

> Each method parameter can be specified in one of three modes: `in`, `out`, or `inout`. An `out` parameter is essentially an auxiliary return value, although these are moderately cumbersome to use from script contexts and should therefore be avoided if reasonable. An `inout` parameter is an in parameter whose value may be changed as a result of the method; these parameters are rather annoying to use and should generally be avoided if at all possible.

---

You are right, `void` means that the function does not return anything, but the [`void` operator does exist](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void.html) (though it has nothing to do with the interface description).